# how to create new attribute product take the value of an another attribute in magento?

Tags: magento

I want to create new attribute product magento wicht take the value of another attribute after save product, like url key attribute whiche take the value of sku whene saving product .

please have you any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Have you tried using an observer that's called on the product save event?

Comment: i'm new in magento , can you show me how to do that please ?

Comment: That's a bit out of scope for this site, but here's a place to start reading (although there are others, just search for "magento observers" and things like that): http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

Comment: thanks a lof Mike ,  that's give me tip to do that's after save product